# Null navigation property in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I am learning ASP.NET Core MVC. I got confused with difference between using `@Model.NavigationProperty.SubProperty` and `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>modelItem.NavigationProperty.SubProperty` to access navigation property. Details are presented below.

I have two entities Bag and Category that is FK in Bag.

```
    public class Bag
    {
        public int BagID { get; set; }
        [Required,Display(Name ="Bag Name")]
        public string BagName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Image")]
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int SupplierID { get; set; }

        public ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Bag> Bags { get; set; }
    }
```

When I create a new Bag, I did

```
public async Task<IActionResult> 
        Create([Bind("BagID,BagName,CategoryID,Description,Price,SupplierID")] Bag bag)
        {

        bag.Category = _context.Categories.Single(c => c.CategoryID == bag.CategoryID);
        bag.Supplier= _context.Suppliers.Single(s => s.SupplierID== bag.SupplierID);
        //....
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          _context.Add(bag);
          await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
      //....  
        return View(bag);
    }
```

Basically, I bind CategoryID and explicitly assigned a Category to a Bag when it's created.

When displaying bag and category name, it involves the Index action in controller as below

```
var Bags = from bags in _context.Bags
          select bags;  //Retrieve all bags 

   Bags.Include(b => b.Category.CategoryName).Include(b=>b.Supplier.FullName); //Load navigation property

            return View(await Bags.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
```

and the view:

```
<h4>@bag.BagName - @bag.Category.CategoryName</h4>
```

but this gives me the NullReference Exception at the line with `<h4>` tag. Removing `AsNoTracking()` doesn't change anything.

However, when I changed to use `<h4>@bag.BagName - @Html.DisplayFor(b=>bag.Category.CategoryName)</h4>` in the view, it does not matter if I use `AsNoTracking()` or not, I got no exception and CategoryName displayed. This is confusing me because the same model got two results.

So what's the difference between the two approaches, and what is better choice?

Thank you all coders!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `@Model.NavigationProperty.SubProperty` requires that both `Model` and `NavigationProperty` are not `null`. It is no different from accessing the `SubProperty` property in a method.

Using `Html.DisplayFor()` however uses the models metadata to generate the html and both `Model` and `NavigationProperty` can be `null` because the method does not directly access the property.

One of the main uses of `DisplayFor()` is to make use of any `[DisplayFormat]` attribute applied to the property. For example you can specify a text to be render if the value of the property is `null` using the `NullDisplayText` property, or render a `DateTime` or numeric property in a specific format using the `DataFormatString` property.

In your case the query should be

```
var Bags = db.Bags.Include(b => b.Category).Include(b => b.Supplier);
return View(await Bags.ToListAsync());
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Your answer is clear to understand. But I'm still confused, because when I use 'DisplayFor()' the CategoryName can be accessed and showed, which means it is not null, is it? Then why do I get Null Reference exception when using '@Model.NavigationProperty.SubProperty' ??